# Present Continuous (i.e. "Loading...") in a Software Status Message

Tags: informatique, temps-grammatical

In English, software will commonly indicate its status using the present continuous tense:

- "Downloading..."
- "Restarting..."
- "Setting up your preferences..."

Is there a common equivalency for such messages in French? Or do they more commonly follow conventions on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use "en cours" :

- Téléchargement en cours
- Redémarrage en cours
- Réglage de vos préférences en cours

Which means literally "… in progress".

Comment: I think `en cours` was exactly what I was looking for. I kept gravitating to `En train de ...` but I knew that sounded impossibly silly.

Comment: I think "Enregistrement des préférences en cours", could be a mistake.

First, "Setting up" means "Restore" not "Save".
Secondly, it is valuable to customize the message for the user and I will translate "your" by "vos".

I would suggest : "Chargement de vos préférences en cours"

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'll change that

Comment: To set up means something akin to “*mettre en place*” rather than “*restaurer*“. With your sentences, I would use “*Réglages de vos préférences*” (well, actually, I would use “*des préférences*”).

Comment: If anyone has any other suggestion, feel free to edit my answer!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that sometimes the corresponding noun is used:

- Téléchargement...
- Redémarrage...
- Enregistrement...